# Ruby on Rails NoMethodError in Posts#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been attempting to write a web blog application based off this [link](http://railsinstallfest.org/guides/installfest4/getting_started/). I am getting a 
Ruby on Rails NoMethodError in Posts#show error when I got to click on a post.

The error states: `"undefined method post_comments_path"` on the line: `<%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>`

This is in my app/views/posts/show.html.erb script. This script is as follows:

```
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

 <%= render :partial => @post %>

 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
 <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

 <h2>Comments</h2>
 <div id="comments">
  <%= render :partial => @post.comments %>
 </div>

<%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body, "New comment" %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Add comment" %></p>
<% end %>
```

With the partial:

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
  <p>
    <strong>
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
    </strong>
    <br/>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I believe though the issue may be in my routes.rb file. The tutorial states to have:

```
QuickBlog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, :only => [:create]
  end

  # root :to => 'welcome#index'
end
```

but I could not get my server to load with this configuration. Instead my routes file is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments
  resources :posts

  devise_for :users
  root "pages#home"
  get "about" => "pages#about"
end
```

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated as I have not found another page with a similar issue with relation to the error.

When I update my routes.rb file to be the same as the tutorial it is as follows:

```
QuickBlog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, :only => [:create]
  end

  # root :to => 'welcome#index'

  devise_for :users
  root "pages#home"
  get "about" => "pages#about"
end
```

I the receive the error in the terminal:

```
routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant QuickBlog (NameError)
```

My comments controller is:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create!(comment_params)
    redirect_to @post
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

Comment: Show your controller..Please

Comment: @Connor See my answer please, it's because of a mismatch in the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your routes.rb file to this. The error you get with the routes.rb from the tutorial is because it's using the application name instead of `Rails.application.routes.draw`. This changed in a Rails 4.1.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, :only => [:create]
  end

  # root :to => 'welcome#index'
end
```