# Error Found NoMethodError in Posts#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-datastore

So I'm working on a social web app using cloud datastore and ruby on rails. I've completed the crud operations for the posting aspect of the app and I'm trying to crud operations for my comment aspect. I'm running into an error when I try to render my comments form in the individual post page. I get an error and I think it has something to do with either one of my controllers or my erb files. I've been looking at for a long time now so hopefully someone can shed some light on it. I tried this solution I found, but it didn't work. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022557/ruby-on-rails-nomethoderror-in-postsshow/%22link%22)

For reference, I'm basically following the Google Datastore Bookshelf Tutorial App. [BookShelf Tutorial App](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore/%22Bookshelf%20Tutorial%20App%22)

**Here is my posts controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  PER_PAGE = 10

  def index
     @post, @cursor = Post.query limit: PER_PAGE, cursor: params[:cursor]
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new post_params

    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Posted"
      redirect_to posts_path(@post)
    else
      render :new
      end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update post_params
       flash[:success] = "Updated Book"
      redirect_to posts_path(@post)
    else
      render :edit
      end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
      end
end
```

**Here is my comments controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
        end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

**Comment model**

```
require "google/cloud/datastore"

class Comment
  include ActiveModel::Model
    attr_accessor :id, :body

    # Return a Google::Cloud::Datastore::Dataset for the configured dataset.
    # The dataset is used to create, read, update, and delete entity objects.
    def self.dataset
      @dataset ||= Google::Cloud::Datastore.new(
        project: Rails.application.config.
                      database_configuration[Rails.env]["dataset_id"]
      )
end

 def to_entity
    post.parent            = dataset.key "Post"
    entity                 = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Entity.new
    entity.key             = post
    entity["body"]         = body
    entity
  end

  # [START from_entity]
  def self.from_entity entity
    comment = Comment.new
    comment.id = entity.key.id
    entity.properties.to_hash.each do |name, value|
      comment.send "#{name}=", value if comment.respond_to? "#{name}="
    end
    comment
  end
  # [END from_entity]

  # Save the book to Datastore.
# @return true if valid and saved successfully, otherwise false.
def save
  if valid?
    entity = to_entity
    Book.dataset.save entity
    self.id = entity.key.id
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

 def persisted?
    id.present?
  end
```

**Post Model**

```
require "google/cloud/datastore"

class Post
    include ActiveModel::Model
    attr_accessor :id, :title, :body

    # Return a Google::Cloud::Datastore::Dataset for the configured dataset.
     # The dataset is used to create, read, update, and delete entity objects.
        def self.dataset
        @dataset ||= Google::Cloud::Datastore.new(
        project: Rails.application.config.
                     database_configuration[Rails.env]["dataset_id"]
    )


end

# Query Book entities from Cloud Datastore.
#
# returns an array of Book query results and a cursor
# that can be used to query for additional results.
def self.query options = {}
  query = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Query.new
  query.kind "Post"
  query.limit options[:limit]   if options[:limit]
  query.cursor options[:cursor] if options[:cursor]

  results = dataset.run query
  posts   = results.map {|entity| Post.from_entity entity }

  if options[:limit] && results.size == options[:limit]
    next_cursor = results.cursor
  end

  return posts, next_cursor
end

def to_entity
  entity                 = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Entity.new
  entity.key             = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Key.new "Post", id
  entity["title"]        = title
  entity["body"]         = body
  entity
end

  # [START from_entity]
def self.from_entity entity
  post = Post.new
  post.id = entity.key.id
  entity.properties.to_hash.each do |name, value|
    post.send "#{name}=", value if post.respond_to? "#{name}="
  end
  post
end
 # [END from_entity]

  # [START find]
  # Lookup Post by ID.  Returns Post or nil.
  def self.find id
    query    = Google::Cloud::Datastore::Key.new "Post", id.to_i
    entities = dataset.lookup query

    from_entity entities.first if entities.any?
  end
  # [END find]


 # [START validations]
  # Add Active Model validation support to Book class.
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :title, presence: true

  # [END validations]

  # [START update]
  # Set attribute values from provided Hash and save to Datastore.
  def update attributes
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send "#{name}=", value if respond_to? "#{name}="
    end
    save
  end
  # [END update]

   # [START destroy]
  def destroy
    Post.dataset.delete Google::Cloud::Datastore::Key.new "Post", id
  end
  # [END destroy]

  # Save the book to Datastore.
# @return true if valid and saved successfully, otherwise false.
def save
  if valid?
    entity = to_entity
    Post.dataset.save entity
    self.id = entity.key.id
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

def persisted?
    id.present?
  end


end
```

**My show.html.erb file**

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
<p><%= @post.body %></p>
<hr>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post), :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(@post), 
                        method: :delete,
                        data:   {confirm: 'Are You Sure?'},
                        :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>


<%= render 'comments/form'%>
```

**This is the comments html erb file**

```
<h3>Comments</h3>
<%= @post.comment.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="well">
    </p><%= link_to '[X]', [comment.post, comment], 
                        method: :delete,
                        data:   {confirm: 'Are You Sure?'} %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**This is the error log**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `comment' for #<Post:0xbb05498>):
    1: <h3>Add Comment</h3>
    2: <%= form_for([@post, @post.comment.build]) do |f| %>
    3:  <div class="form-group">
    4:          <%= f.label:body %><br>
    5:          <%= f.text_area(:body, {:class => 'form-control'}) %>

app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_comments__form_html_erb__676677109_98008740'
app/views/posts/show.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_erb___922952118_98050956'
```

Comment: You should have posted your `Post` model. It probably `has_many :comments`, right? If so, it should be `@post.comments.build`, I suspect.

Comment: Well since I'm using Google Datastore. I don't believe i can use that since datastore uses ancestor relationships

Comment: Show your Post and Comment models.

Comment: I think it's because I'm not properly declaring the comment model or entity as child of the post entity. @hashrocket

Comment: You should have a has_many on the posts model and a belongs_to on the comments model.

Comment: Cloud Datastore doesn't use model associations @hashrocket